# How can I extract a type from a union of (Type | Type[]) to get Type?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get the type of an exported union type by the array of it inside as represented in the playground above. What would be the best way to do this without using the `Type` itself (as it is non-exported)?

```
interface CurrentType {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

type ExportedType = CurrentType | CurrentType[]

type DesiredType = CurrentType

// How can I get to DesiredType from CurrentType?
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcpQuAKgTwAcUBvAWAChlk4AuZAZzClAHMBuS6gI3pHQC23aJwoBfSpTBEUAUQAehAPZRIAEwLFkAXjSZseGcgA+erDjCaIAbQC6kitK0ARCA2DYNR3RnOHiDgD0gcgAEkoA7sgIcCDIAJLIrBBgyGBKyK7unlbIMFBKAmYGljIA-EA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exclude arrays of `unknown` type from the union

```
type DesiredType = Exclude<ExportedType, Array<unknown>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a utility which will operate on a type, extracting from each of its array constituents a union of its members:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIFcpQuAKgTwAcUBvAKGWTgC5kBnMKUAcwG4LkAjWkdAW07R2AXzJkwRFAFEAHoQD2USABMCxZAF40mbHknIAPtqw4waiAG0AumInqAgljj4pAGwh9TAeSjmAPLgAfJrIuMgQMpAgynTI2HDK8iCu+FQg+NbIAPyhFrwC0FbItLjs4vq4cFDMEGb6Wo5Qzm4e3r6SfrIKShCqkoHsAPSDlMgAelm2+vYg8mAAFtBdiirmIfmCUIb0jCzWZXYoAHKKAMohjc3unuA+-jNzi1DLPX3EA2TDoxNkQA)

```ts
type ArrayElementOrType<T> = T extends readonly any[] ? T[number] : T;
```

This has the advantage of working on other unions of different "base" types:

```ts
type AnotherExportedType = number | string[];

type NorS = ArrayElementOrType<AnotherExportedType>;
//   ^? string | number
```

and in your case, it simply collapses into your desired target type:

```ts
type TargetType = ArrayElementOrType<ExportedType>;
//   ^? CurrentType
```